# Find shortest path and save it with geometry

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, shortest-path

With the guide of  [Network analysis library](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html)

I found the shortest route on the network I'm analyzing. The script I used is as follows:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.networkanalysis import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *

vl = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
director = QgsLineVectorLayerDirector(vl, -1, '', '', '', 3)
properter = QgsDistanceArcProperter()
director.addProperter(properter)
crs = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().destinationCrs()
builder = QgsGraphBuilder(crs)

pStart = QgsPoint(594869.256,4279586.388z)
pStop = QgsPoint(594011.309,4279760.098)

tiedPoints = director.makeGraph(builder, [pStart, pStop])
graph = builder.graph()

tStart = tiedPoints[0]
tStop = tiedPoints[1]

idStart = graph.findVertex(tStart)
tree = QgsGraphAnalyzer.shortestTree(graph, idStart, 0)

idStart = tree.findVertex(tStart)
idStop = tree.findVertex(tStop)

if idStop == -1:
  print("Path not found")
else:
  p = []
  while (idStart != idStop):
    l = tree.vertex(idStop).inArc()
    if len(l) == 0:
      break
    e = tree.arc(l[0])
    p.insert(0, tree.vertex(e.inVertex()).point())
    idStop = e.outVertex()

  p.insert(0, tStart)
  rb = QgsRubberBand(qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas())
  rb.setColor(Qt.green)

  for pnt in p:
    rb.addPoint(pnt)
```

Unfortunately, the result I get is a path highlighted in a different color. Is there a way to save the path as a shapefile containing the length of the path as information? Or, even better, save this information in a text file?

I'm following this suggestion:

```
lastPoint = None
d = 0
for point in p:
    if lastPoint is not None:
         dx = point.x - lastPoint.x
         dy = point.y - lastPoint.y  
         d += sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
    lastPoint = point
print "distance is "+str(d/1000.0)+"km"
```

but I get an error:
File "path/to/scipt.py", line 52, in 
    dx = point.x - lastPoint.x
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

Comment: at this line: ` p.insert(0, tStart)` you're having a complete set of points in a list `p`. Those are QgsPoint objects. So you have a list of QgsPoints, you can easily create shapefile out of them, or, if you wish, extract their X and Y and save to some text file. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389616/how-to-add-feature-in-shape-file-with-pyqgis) answer might help you creating shapefile out of points. If you want to store X and Y of each point, just iterate over them in the last for loop and access them using `pnt.x()` and `pnt.y()`. Does this solve the problem for you?

Comment: @adamczi can you explain me how to use point.x() and point.y()?

Comment: I see you already got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.networkanalysis import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from math import *

vl = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
director = QgsLineVectorLayerDirector(vl, -1, '', '', '', 3)
properter = QgsDistanceArcProperter()
director.addProperter(properter)
crs = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().destinationCrs()
builder = QgsGraphBuilder(crs)

pStart = QgsPoint(594869.256,4279586.388)
pStop = QgsPoint(594011.309,4279760.098)

tiedPoints = director.makeGraph(builder, [pStart, pStop])
graph = builder.graph()

tStart = tiedPoints[0]
tStop = tiedPoints[1]

idStart = graph.findVertex(tStart)
tree = QgsGraphAnalyzer.shortestTree(graph, idStart, 0)

idStart = tree.findVertex(tStart)
idStop = tree.findVertex(tStop)

if idStop == -1:
  print("Path not found")
else:
  p = []
  while (idStart != idStop):
    l = tree.vertex(idStop).inArc()
    if len(l) == 0:
      break
    e = tree.arc(l[0])
    p.insert(0, tree.vertex(e.inVertex()).point())
    idStop = e.outVertex()

  p.insert(0, tStart)
  rb = QgsRubberBand(qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas())
  rb.setColor(Qt.green)

  lastPoint = None
  d = 0

  for pnt in p:
    rb.addPoint(pnt)


    if lastPoint is not None:
            dx = pnt.x() - lastPoint.x()
            dy = pnt.y() - lastPoint.y()  
            d += sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
    lastPoint = pnt
print "distance is "+str(d/1000.0)+"km"
```

Comment: That's a pity... This script doesn't work in QGIS 3.12 anymore. I'm getting `name 'QgsLineVectorLayerDirector' is not defined`. In fact, there is no QgsLineVector* in auto completion. Was It renamed/replaced?